# How to escape html placeholder attribute in rendered vue

Tags: encoding, vuejs2, vue-component

I've setup a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jessycormier/qu1275ae/) to showcase the issue.

```html
<div id="app">
  <strong>{{title}}</strong><br>
  <input type="text" :placeholder="icon" />
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Vue Rendered Info',
    icon: '&#xf002;'
  }
});
```

This is just a sample *(check the jsFiddle for a working sample)* of what I'm trying to do. In my real project I have a .vue component; regardless of my icon being in the data or directly in the  I have the same issue. but for the sake of stackoverflow I've made a "working" example of the issue in the jsFiddle.

I'm attempting to place a Font-Awesome icon inside of the placeholder text of an input.

Any insight on how to solve this issue would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use Unicode characters in Javascript you must properly escape them. To quote Microsoft's page on [Special Characters (JavaScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/special-characters-javascript)

> You can specify a Unicode character by using the \uhhhh escape
>   sequence, where hhhh is a four-digit hexadecimal number.

The unicode identifier for the [font-awesome magnify-glass icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/) is F002.

As such you'll want the following instead:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'Vue Rendered Info',
        icon: '\uf002'
    }
});
```

Comment: YES this is works perfectly! Do you have any resources to explain why this is working and the other is not. I have a hunch it has to do with Vue taking the template and converting it into a JavaScript String...

Comment: Agreed that one stumped me :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If somebody is using the font awesome v5.x don't forget to add class="fa"